# AngularJS: Checking if user is on a specific route that uses params

Tags: angularjs

If I have a route as such:

```
$routeProvider.when('/event/:id', { templateUrl: 'view/event-details.html', controller: 'EventDetailCtrl'});
```

Is there a way to check if the user is on the `/event/:id` route

Is using `if ($location.path().indexOf('/event/') !== -1)` a safe way to check if the user is on this route?

Comment: if the controller `EventDetailCtrl` is only used for that route, then on controller load you are on that route

Comment: That's not checking the route, that is checking which controller is loaded. Say if I, for whatever reason, use the same controller for two different routes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. Either you can use a `console.log` in controller or another way you can use an `ng-init` in the template URL to call any function. So if the template is loaded then it will call the function and hence you get to know that the user is on that route :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you want to achieve. Your `$routeProvider` relays your incoming request to a particular `controller`. It is inside the `controller` you can fully access the tokens parsed by your `$routeProvider`.

Declare `$routeParams` in your controller to access the tokens of your matched route.

```
$routeProvider
.when('/event/:id', { templateUrl: 'view/event-details.html', controller: 'EventDetailCtrl'});
```

In your `controller`:

```
.controller('EventDetailCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
})
```

Comment: I'm not trying to read `$routeParams`, I'm trying to find out if the user is on the current route: `/event/:id`. I am using this outside of a controller, for example in `$httpProvider` when responses are incoming to the application and I'm handling errors from my API.